# Retrieve Contact Information such as Employee Id from Open Outlook Properties using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, contacts, outlook-2010

Whenever we right click on an Email Address, and click on Open Outlook Properties, a contact card is open as shown, I want to extract Employee ID and other details from Employee Info tab through VBA, I am able to extract First name etc by using following code.

```
Set OutRecipients = OutMail.Recipients.Add(EmailAddress)
OutRecipients.Resolve
Name = OutRecipients.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Name
FirstName = OutRecipients.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.FirstName
LastName = OutRecipients.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.LastName
Alias = OutRecipients.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias
JobTitle = OutRecipients.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.JobTitle
Department = OutRecipients.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Department
PrimarySmtpAddress = OutRecipients.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress

Output_sh.Cells(lCnt, 1) = Name
Output_sh.Cells(lCnt, 2) = FirstName
Output_sh.Cells(lCnt, 3) = LastName
Output_sh.Cells(lCnt, 4) = Alias
Output_sh.Cells(lCnt, 5) = JobTitle
Output_sh.Cells(lCnt, 6) = Department
Output_sh.Cells(lCnt, 7) = PrimarySmtpAddress
```

[Open Outlook properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6eNG.png)

[Employee info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E3NZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser) method returns an `ExchangeUser` object that represents the `AddressEntry` if the `AddressEntry` belongs to an Exchange AddressList object such as the Global Address List (GAL) and corresponds to an Exchange user.

If you take a look at the [ExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser#properties) properties you may find all of them.

ExchangeUser is derived from the AddressEntry object, and is returned instead of an AddressEntry when the caller performs a query interface on the AddressEntry object.

This object provides first-class access to properties applicable to Exchange users such as `FirstName`, `JobTitle`, `LastName`, and `OfficeLocation`. You can also access other properties specific to the Exchange user that are not exposed in the object model through the `PropertyAccessor` object. Note that some of the explicit built-in properties are read-write properties. Setting these properties requires the code to be running under an appropriate Exchange administrator account; without sufficient permissions, calling the `ExchangeUser.Update` method will result in a "permission denied" error. You can use [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or [OutlooSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) utilities for exploring low-level properties.